# How to Reset members of an instance Class without recreate a new instance?

Tags: c#, class, nested, reset

I'd like to `Reset` to there default values all of the members of my class instance `CommunicationErrorsDetails`.
This class is part of a nested class `MyNestedClassInstance`.

This is what I'd like to do :

```
MyNestedClassInstance.CommunicationErrorsDetails.Reset()
```

This a sample of my nested class `MyNestedClass` which instance is `MyNestedClassInstance` :

```
public class MyNestedClass : ICloneable
{
    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Communication errors count
    /// </summary>
    public class CommunicationErrorsDetailsType : ICloneable
    {
        public int RetryCount;
        public int CRCErrorCount;
        public int DataBytesNotExpectedCount;
        public int TooMuchDataReceivedCount;
        public int ResponseDataAddressNotEqualCount;
        public int BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateStartCount;
        public int BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateSendFrameCount;
        public int BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateDataResponseReceivedCount;
        public int ExceptionCount;
        public int NakcReceivedCount;
        public int AckTimeoutCount;
        public int DataTimeoutCount;
        public double DataTimeoutRate;

        public bool HasCommunicationErrors
        {
            get => RetryCount > 0
                || CRCErrorCount > 0
                || DataBytesNotExpectedCount > 0
                || TooMuchDataReceivedCount > 0
                || ResponseDataAddressNotEqualCount > 0
                || BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateStartCount > 0
                || BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateSendFrameCount > 0
                || BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateDataResponseReceivedCount > 0
                || ExceptionCount > 0
                || NakcReceivedCount > 0
                || AckTimeoutCount > 0
                || DataTimeoutCount > 0;
        }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return MemberwiseClone();
        }

        internal void Reset()
        {
            // ... ?
        }
    }
    public CommunicationErrorsDetailsType CommunicationErrorsDetails = new CommunicationErrorsDetailsType();

    ...
    // Other nested classes
    ...
}
```

How can I achieve `Reset()` without having to recreate a new instance and without having to reset manually all members that can be of different types ?

All members are simple types (not classes).

Furthermore, I cannot change the structure of all classes of same type because we have several years of code structured like this.

Thank you for your help.
Regards

Comment: Doing it manually will be most efficient way to do it ;)

Comment: Modern IDE provide features to copy multiple lines. Then you can set their values to `default`, which will be default value of corresponding type.

Comment: For maintenance purpose and bug proof, I'd avoid to add each members manually. If I forgot to add a new member, a bug will be created also.

Comment: To prevent "forgoting" write tests ;)

Comment: @Fabio , when I was saying "If I forgot ..." I was intended to say if a developper "forgot to". Indeed, we tries to find software patterns that prevent bugs in our projects.

Comment: I regret to inform you, that no such patterns exists, which will prevent bugs. If you write tests, failing tests will guide developers to keep on the right track.

Comment: @Fabio, I know this, but patterns aim can also to builds more robust architecture, in my opinion.

Comment: Make the class immutable, no need to reset anything, simply go back to the one and only `MyImmutableClass.Default`.

Comment: immutable class will not answer the simple need to reset fields without having to duplicate resetting each fields each time a new field is added into the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Reflexion you can achieve what you want and with the help of 
[DefaultExpression Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.defaultexpression?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

```
internal void Reset()
{
    // Retrieves only the fields of this Class
    var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance
                       | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                       | BindingFlags.Public;
    List<FieldInfo> members = this.GetType()
                                  .GetFields(bindingFlags)
                                  .Where(f => f.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                                  .Where(value => value != null)
                                  .ToList();

    // Set all fields to its default type value
    for (int i = 0; i < members.Count(); i++)
    {
        // This expression represents the default value of a type
        // (0 for integer, null for a string, etc.)
        Expression defaultExpr = Expression.Default(typeof(byte));
        // The following statement first creates an expression tree,
        // then compiles it, and then executes it.
        var defaultValue = Expression.Lambda<Func<byte>>(defaultExpr).Compile()();
        // Set the default value
        members[i].SetValue(this, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I expected. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to take advantage of the fact that `struct`s in .NET can easily reset themselves by assigning `this`.

An example code sample is below (also available at https://dotnetfiddle.net/zhfjcg). The key bit is:

```
public void Reset()
{
    this = new TheData();
}
```

This will reset / reinitialise the `TheData` object - so that all fields are reset back to their default.

The code sample also uses properties to expose the struct data in `CommunicationErrorsDetailsType`. That isn't strictly necessary, but is likely a good idea.

Additionally, this technique makes cloning *much* faster (vs `MemberwiseClone`) assuming the contents of the `struct` don't contain anything with fancy cloning requirements, since assigning the `struct` to a new variable will "automatically" clone it.

```
using System;

namespace WhatEver
{
    public struct TheData
    {
        public int RetryCount;
        public int CRCErrorCount;
        public int DataBytesNotExpectedCount;
        public int TooMuchDataReceivedCount;
        public int ResponseDataAddressNotEqualCount;
        public int BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateStartCount;
        public int BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateSendFrameCount;
        public int BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateDataResponseReceivedCount;
        public int ExceptionCount;
        public int NakcReceivedCount;
        public int AckTimeoutCount;
        public int DataTimeoutCount;
        public double DataTimeoutRate;

        public void Reset()
        {
            this = new TheData();
        }
    }

    public class CommunicationErrorsDetailsType
    {
        private TheData data;

        public int DataTimeoutCount
        {
            get
            {
                return data.DataTimeoutCount;
            }
            set
            {
                data.DataTimeoutCount = value;
            }
        }

        public bool HasCommunicationErrors
        {
            get => data.RetryCount > 0
                || data.CRCErrorCount > 0
                || data.DataBytesNotExpectedCount > 0
                || data.TooMuchDataReceivedCount > 0
                || data.ResponseDataAddressNotEqualCount > 0
                || data.BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateStartCount > 0
                || data.BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateSendFrameCount > 0
                || data.BytesReceivedInCommunicationStateDataResponseReceivedCount > 0
                || data.ExceptionCount > 0
                || data.NakcReceivedCount > 0
                || data.AckTimeoutCount > 0
                || data.DataTimeoutCount > 0;
        }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return MemberwiseClone();
        }

        internal void Reset()
        {
            data.Reset();
        }
    }

    public class ToRun
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var hereWeGo = new CommunicationErrorsDetailsType();

            hereWeGo.DataTimeoutCount = 4;
            Console.WriteLine(hereWeGo.DataTimeoutCount);
            hereWeGo.Reset();
            Console.WriteLine(hereWeGo.DataTimeoutCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer another idea. Use an indirection.

```
class Instance
{
    public Holder<int> IntValue1;
    public Holder<int> IntValue2;
    public Holder<double> DoubleValue1;

    public void Reset()
    {
        Holder.Reset();
    }

    internal class Holder
    {
        public static event EventHandler OnReset;

        public static void Reset()
        {
            OnReset?.Invoke(null, null);
        }
    }

    public class Holder<T>
    {
        private Holder()
        {
            Holder.OnReset += (_, __) => Value = default(T);
        }

        public T Value { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator T(Holder<T> holder)
        {
            return holder.Value;
        }

        public static implicit operator Holder<T>(T value)
        {
            return new Holder<T>() { Value = value };
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
instance.IntValue1 = 123;
instance.IntValue2 = 234;
instance.DoubleValue1 = 0.5;

instance.Reset();
```

Comment: This solution is very interesting, but I cannot change all our huge code. But If I had to start from scratch I'd use this solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with redesigning your public fields to properties (which is a best practice anyways) you can use an internal dictionary to store the values:

```
private Dictionary<string, int> _values = new Dictionary<string, int>();

private int get_val(string key) 
{
    int output;
    _values.TryGetValue(key, out output);
    return output;
}

public int RetryCount {get {return get_val("RetryCount");} set {_values["RetryCount"] = value;}
public int CRCErrorCount {get {return get_val("CRCErrorCount");} set {_values["CRCErrorCount"] = value;}
public int DataBytesNotExpectedCount {get {return get_val("CRCErDataBytesNotExpectedCount rorCount");} set {_values["DataBytesNotExpectedCount "] = value;}
...
```

Then "resetting" an instance is just a one-liner

```
internal void Reset() { _values.Clear(); }
```

Comment: See my comment on @weichch solution. Thank you for your help.